# Remove null values from Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've sql query setup that produces this output:

| ID | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | null |
| 1 | 234 | null |
| 1 | 456 | null |
| 1 | null | 789 |
| 1 | null | 012 |

I need the output to be following:

| ID | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 789 |
| 1 | 234 | 012 |
| 1 | 456 | null |

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, it's generally a good idea to be as specific as possible in words with what you're looking for. Showing the result you want is great, but by itself, it forces anyone looking at this to assume what you're looking for, frequently getting it wrong in the process and wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that this (what you want) should be already done. If that's not possible, see if this helps. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, id1, id2) as
  2    -- result produced by current query
  3    (select 1, 123, null from dual union all
  4     select 1, 234, null from dual union all
  5     select 1, 456, null from dual union all
  6     select 1, null, '789' from dual union all
  7     select 1, null, '012' from dual
  8    ),
  9  taba as
 10    -- ID1 and row ordinal number (for joining purposes)
 11    (select id, id1, row_number() over (order by id1) rn
 12     from test
 13    ),
 14  tabb as
 15    -- ID2 and row ordinal number (for joining purposes)
 16    (select id, id2, row_number() over (order by id2) rn
 17     from test
 18    )
 19  -- join them on ID and RN
 20  select  a.id, a.id1, b.id2
 21  from taba a join tabb b on a.id = b.id and a.rn = b.rn
 22  where a.id1 is not null
 23  order by a.id, a.id1, b.id2;

        ID        ID1 ID2
---------- ---------- ---
         1        123 012
         1        234 789
         1        456

SQL>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfect. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID, ID1, ID2
FROM table1
WHERE ID1 IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use case statement.
look here: [Multiple conditions with CASE statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031501/multiple-conditions-with-case-statements)
If after that you question continue, don't worry, call me.